# Android Twitter String to Json Array

Tags: java, android, json

I have a URL for a twitter feed and I have created a string from it and I want to put it in a JSONArray so I can call back the individual items. In this case - "text".

[Here's the json](https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=evostikleague&count=10)

**Here's my code**:

```
try {
   // Create a new HTTP Client
   DefaultHttpClient defaultClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
   // Setup the get request
   HttpGet httpGetRequest = new HttpGet(
         "https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=evostikleague&count=10");

   // Execute the request in the client
   HttpResponse httpResponse = defaultClient.execute(httpGetRequest);
   // Grab the response
   BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
         httpResponse.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
   String json = reader.readLine();

   // Instantiate a JSON object from the request response
   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
   List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();

   JSONArray jArray = obj.getJSONArray(json);

   for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
      JSONObject oneObject = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
      items.add(oneObject.getString("text"));
      Log.i("items", "items");
   }

   setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item,
         items));
   ListView list = getListView();
   list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

   list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
               ((TextView) arg1).getText(), 1000).show();
      }

   });

} catch (Exception e) {
   // In your production code handle any errors and catch the individual exceptions
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: its not displaying anything in my list view I'm getting a JSONeexception in my LogCat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to parse the response as `JSONObject` (`{}`), while it is a `JSONArray` (`[]`). You should probably remove the line:

```
// Instantiate a JSON object from the request response
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
```

instead, you need:

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(json);
```

Comment: ok I've edited it and now just getting the red cross it doesn't like json.getString  String json = reader.readLine();

      Log.v(json,"jsonfeed");
   
      
      
    
  
      List<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
     
        
    
   
    
    
     
      for (int i=0; i < json.length(); i++)
      {  
       items.add(json.getString("text"));
        Log.i("items", "items");
      }
     
      setListAdapter ( new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.single_item, items));

Comment: ok figured it out turns out you was right but i also needed to convert into a JSONArray     JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(json);

Answer (score 0):

We need to make JSON object first. For example,

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(resp);
```

jsonObject may contains other JSON Objects or JSON array. How to convert the JSON depends on the String.

```
JSONArray arr  = jsonObject.getJSONArray("arraykey");
```

There is a complete example with some explanation about JSON String to JSON array can be found at http://www.hemelix.com/JSONHandling